# Remove duplicates in string

Tags: r

I have the following data set

```
df <- data.frame(
    path = c("a,b,a", 
        "(direct) / (none),   (direct) / (none), google / cpc,    google / cpc", 
        "f,d", 
        "a,c"
    ) 
)
```

and I wish to remove the duplicated so that my output will be

```
                                                                       path
1:                                                                     a, b
2:                                       (direct) / (none),     google / cpc
3:                                                                     f, d
4:                                                                     a, c
```

I tried this but it does not work for the second row

```
setDT(df)

df$path <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path ), split=","), function(x) {
    paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')
})
```

Comment: You are on the good way. Try with `split=",\\s*"` to remove unwanted blank spaces. Also, if you intend to use `data.table`, use proper grammar to avoid copies: `df[,path:=sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path ), split=",\\s*"), function(x) {paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')})]`.

Comment: That was awesome @nicola, please consider writing your answers below then I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. The only thing is that you need to split with `",\\s*"` instead of just `","`. In the latter case, calling `unique` won't produce the wanted output, since some string may differ for the number of blank spaces. If you remove them when you split, you solve this issue.

On another note, since you used `setDT(df)`, I guess you are using `data.table`. If so, you need to use proper `data.table` grammar to avoid copies:

```
df[,path:=sapply(
   strsplit(as.character(df$path ), split=",\\s*"), 
    function(x) {paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')})]
```

will modify the `path` column *by reference*.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is the initial white space in the second strings. Are you trying to preserve that, or are you willing to lose it? If you're willing to lose it, then

```
df$path <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), split=","), function(x) {
    paste(unique(trimws(x)), collapse = ', ') } )
```

is what you want:

```
> df$path <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), split=","), function(x) {
+     paste(unique(trimws(x)), collapse = ', ') } )
> df$path
[1] "a, b"                            "(direct) / (none), google / cpc"
[3] "f, d"                            "a, c"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic logic behind below code :

i)split each row on "," ,         (ii) remove whitespace  (iii) take unique values
(iv) collapse back on "," and paste

```
t = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,",")))), collapse = ","))
df=data.frame(t)
# df
#                               t
#1                            a,b
#2 (direct) / (none),google / cpc
#3                            f,d
#4                            a,c
```